# How to check if input is valid and keep asking for input if it's not

Tags: c++, validation, while-loop

Can anybody please explain why this while loop is not working properly?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
void ask_user(int a, int b){
    char choice = ' '; 
    while(choice != 'q' && choice != 'a' && choice != 's' && choice != 'm'){
        cout << "choose operation" << endl; 
        cout << "a to add, s to subtract, m to multiply and q to quit" << endl; 
        cout << "----------------------------" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        switch(choice){
            case 'a' : cout << "a + b = " << a + b; 
            break;
            case 's' : cout << "a - b = " << a + b; 
            break;
            case 'm' : cout << "a * b = " << a + b;
            break;
            case 'q' : break; 
            default: cout << "please Enter a valid choice " << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    ask_user(7, 9); 
    return 0; 
}
```

If I enter p for exemple which is not valid then it works fine and asks for valid input again,

but if I enter pp that's when it starts bugging and prints the message twice. If I enter ppp it

prints three times etc...

Comment: Add `cin.ignore()` to the `default` case.

Comment: Also, in the `switch` statements, you forget all the breaks except for the `q` case (which breaks the `switch` and not the `while`).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did but it works first time only then if if I do ppp again it prints 3 times

Comment: That is because of the second bug that @Fareanor  mentioned.

Comment: @drescherjm fixed it but still the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you have a misunderstanding of how `switch` works. Each case must end with `break` statement so that the following one won't get executed.
Which means that a `break` will break the `switch`, not the `while`.

But the main issue is that the logic of your program is wrong.
You should not loop over the validity of the given input, let the `switch` statement handle that in the `default` clause.

Instead you should loop over a flag that will be set when the user press the <kbd>q</kbd> key.

So considering you have the following functions defined to respectively display the menu and ask for the operands to operate on (defined for code readability):

```
void display_menu(char & choice)
{
    std::cout << "Operation:\na: Addition\nm: Multiplication\ns: Substraction\nq: Quit\n";
    std::cin >> choice;
}
void ask_operands(int & a, int & b)
{
    std::cout << "\na ?";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "\nb ?";
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The logic of your code can be then rewritten as:

```
int main()
{
    bool quit = false;
    char choice;
    int a, b;

    ask_operands(a, b); // Ask the user which operands to use
    while(!quit)        // loop over the flag
    {
        display_menu(choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 'a': std::cout << (a+b);
                      break;
            case 'm': std::cout << (a*b);
                      break;
            case 's': std::cout << (a-b);
                      break;
            case 'q': std::cout << "Exiting...";
                      quit = true; // Set the flag to false
                      break;
            default: std::cout << "Invalid choice, try again."; //Here you handle the invalid choices (i.e. let the loop iterate again)
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[*Live example*](https://godbolt.org/z/bxodq7WhP)</kbd>

**Note:** If you want the user to be able to change the value of the operands at each iteration, just move the `ask_operands(a, b);` call inside the loop.

Comment: it seems like your code has the same bug sir. did you try it? I entered an invalid input and it did the same thing as my code. first I entered x and it printed once then I entered x and it printed 3 times then I entered elon musk and it got crazy. It's not even breaking when I enter the right input

Comment: @ThisIsMe Actually the code works but for single characters only. I've just proposed a simple example to give you the right logic. It was not intended to write all the code for you :) If you want to handle strings, you may be interested to use `std::getline` instead of just `std::cin::operator>>()`. But the structure will remain the same.

Comment: @ThisIsMe Here you have the [reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) about `std::getline()` and even an example of how to use it. Use that to read a line into a `string` instead of a simple `char`.

Comment: And yes, I tried it, I linked in the question a live example. And there was also a test for an invalid input (i.e. invalid means an unhandled character). Of course it doesn't handle strings as written there, once again, it was just a skeleton to give you the proper logic. But of course, if you want to handle all possible user inputs, you should read it as a string with `std::getline`, and parse it afterwards, it's safer :)

Comment: ohh yeah getline() that was the missing peace. problem solved thank you again :)